The Feynman Lectures, chapter 18, rotation in 2 dimensions
I was reading through chapter 18 of Richard Feynman's lectures, as found in this link: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_18.html, and was confused to find this formula that he "simply" derived for describing work from a point and a force vector:
$$ \Delta W = F_x \Delta x + F_y \Delta y$$
where $ \Delta W $ is the change in work, $ F_x $ and $ F_y $ are the x and y components of the force applied, and $ \Delta x $ and $ \Delta y $ are the changes in x and y.
What I was thinking is that this sum would only work if the two components of work were independent, but I do not think that they were considering that the x and y should change simultaneously, given they are rotating simultaneously. In contrast to Feynman's formula, I got this:
$$ \Delta W = \sqrt{F_x^2+F_y^2} \sqrt{\Delta x^2 +\Delta y^2} $$
After a while of thinking, I could not figure out how Feynman got his answer and am still wondering who went wrong.

The work done on a body is always the line integral of force along the path the body describes. If we're interested in the work done in a small displacements we may consider only the dot product, which is what Feynman did. It doesn't matter if there is a functional relationship $F_x(F_y)$ or vice versa. How did you arrive at your different formula?

You are looking at the magnitude of work. The dot product has a cosine term. Consider a force acting on an object where the direction of the force is different than the direction of displacement.

Note that $W=\vec F\cdot \vec d$ is the dot product of force and position vectors, not the product of the magnitudes.
Hence,
$$W=\vec F\cdot \vec d=\langle F_x,F_y\rangle\cdot\langle \Delta x,\Delta y\rangle=F_x\Delta x+F_y\Delta y.$$
Alternatively, if you want to use the magnitudes, then you could also express $W=\vec F\cdot \vec d=|\vec F||\vec d|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the force and distance vectors.

Thank you. I guess I just didn't know the proper definition of work.
